# Bootstrap spacing to center 4 boxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the design I want for my site and it involves 4 boxes that I have in a row.

I want these 4 boxes to be centred but also have a space to the left and right of the page.

So I thought I would be clever and use 6 columns leaving the far left and right empty.

This looks great on a full browsers however on mobile obviously it looks terrible as it has spaces that are not required. Can anyone offer and advice on another way to fix this?

http://legaleye.16mb.com/members/index.php

It's still a work in progress but the link shows what I mean if you open in a mobile vs a desktop browse.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Apologises that I'm not near a desktop otherwise I'd mock something out for you but I thought I'd at least point you in the right direction.

I'd create 2 CSS classes, 1 for the left column with `padding-left` and then a right one with `padding-right` and then I'd put that inside a @media query to set the padding to 0 for those classes on mobile (min 480px) as I assume you want the columns vertical on mobile (like standard bootstrap)? I think this is the simplest solution and yea it takes away the complexity of managing 6 columns.

**EDIT:**
The css you should need:

```
.left{
  margin-left:2%;
}

.right{
  margin-left:2%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .left{
        margin:0;
    }
    .right{
        margin:0;
    }
}
```

Then just add the classes to your columns `class="left"`.

Comment: Hi thanks. I'm newish to bootstrap so not sure what an @media query is but I'll try and have a read up on that. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Oh sorry I should've linked this above as well, W3Schools is always the place to start for this. If you get stuck leave me another comment and I'm sure I can point you in the right direction. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp. As a quick overview, media queries are how bootstrap can do CSS changes based on device and screen size so basically they are what make any mobile friendly CSS work well.

Comment: If your still stuck I've put up the CSS I was talking about in my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks again I have done as suggested however it has just made the left a right boxes wider than the middle 2 rather than adding padding to the side of the boxes. Have I don't something wrong?

Comment: i'm trying to put part of the code so you can check if I have done it right ibut I cant get it to work as a code block rather than just a string of text

Comment: Oh use margin instead then. I'll update my code. Let me know if that worked, if not post your code and I'll take a look.

Comment: Still not working :(

<DIV class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 left">
<DIV class="div-square"><A href="http://legaleye.16mb.com/members/blank.html"><I 
class="fa fa-search fa-5x"></I>                       
<H4>Search</H4></A>                       </DIV></DIV>
<DIV class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
<DIV class="div-square"><A href="http://legaleye.16mb.com/members/alerts.php"><I 
class="fa fa-bell fa-5x"></I>                       
<H4>Alerts</H4></A>                       </DIV></DIV>

Comment: Yea, that seems to have just worked in my head :). I'm sure I could get it to work but use this instead which puts the margin on the row. http://www.bootply.com/pS2whjPgcn

Comment: Actually put it in another class so not to change the row directly. You never know what bootstrap might do in the future with margins on a row. http://www.bootply.com/3YS1zFbQNT